# Remove random string from docker container name

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

Even when I run "docker-compose up -d", containers fill a random string as suffix automatically (after _1). However, those strings did not appear few days ago.

I didn't change anything in docker-compose.yml. I am using Docker Desktop for Windows.

Anyone please tell me how to remove them? Thanks.

**nginx_1_874f33129390** should be **nginx_1**.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE         NAMES
ddaca6e6aad3        nginx         nginx_1_874f33129390
c038bc23404c        php-fpm       php-fpm_1_efb57fda5fdb
e65d0468804a        php-worker    php-worker_1_d59af45d7431
660f98415824        workspace     workspace_1_67e1d0a5cc29
db4149e1df85        redis         redis_1_3defcbd0cae2
445f8f6e11b0        mysql         mysql_1_c2d15aaf6137
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably updated your `docker-compose` version, they added this behaviour recently. You can use in your `service` definitions the key `container_name: nginx_1` and the container will have this name. However, take into account that you can have only one replica for each service your are defining `container_name` for. [Read here the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#container_name) and [here the changelog of docker compose (under the changes section)](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.23.0)

Comment: Thank you, @gasc. You're right. I just checked Docker Desktop and it updated to newest version. I didn't change docker-compose.yml as well but have not "container_name" defined. So it's clear that Docker Compose version 1.23.0 changed "<project>_<service>_<index>" to
"<project>_<service>_<index>_<slug>".